# NSNumber/NSString math returns correct value but with a minus sign

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, math

code:

```
-(IBAction)addRounds{
NSString *addText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.roundsF.text];
NSString *totalText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.totalRoundsF.text];

int value = [totalText intValue] - [addText intValue];

NSNumber *val = [NSNumber numberWithInt:value];

NSString *final = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", val.stringValue];

self.totalRoundsF.text = final;
}
```

The above code works perfectly, however when it displays the data into the textfield, it will show something like : `-10` the number 10 is correct, i just dont want a `-` sign. Any help is greatly appreciated, Thank you very much!

Comment: NSLog("%d", value); // what does this say?

Comment: @hd1 It displays the correct value, but with a `-` sign!

Comment: Should it be [addText intValue] - [totalText intValue]?

Comment: It looks like your `roundsF` is *greater* than the total! You should fix it or understand it, rather than masking with an `abs` right away. Also, your code is an incredibly roundabout way of doing what you need: it all can be done in two lines (combine the first four and the last two).

Comment: why the downvote people? people have different skill levels and they are at different stages in their learning process. If one can help, help. Discouraging is bad. Upvoting to negate the downvote...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not want negative value at all? In that case use `abs` absolute value. This will always give you positive values.

Depending on the type of your variable, one of `abs(int)`, `labs(long)`, `llabs(long long)`, `imaxabs(intmax_t)`, `fabsf(float)`, `fabs(double)`, or `fabsl(long double)`.

These functions are part of the C library and are present in Objective-C library as well. You might have to import `math.h` to use them.

so in your case it would be `abs(val); //will give +10`

Answer (score 2):

change `NSNumber *val = [NSNumber numberWithInt:value];` this to `NSNumber *val = [NSNumber numberWithInt:abs(value)];`

Answer (score 1):

```
-(IBAction)addRounds{
    self.totalRoundsF.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [self.roundsF.text intValue] - [self.totalRoundsF.text intValue]];
}
```